# Prove that if $x^9 \equiv 3 \bmod{61}$, then $x^{12}\equiv 34 \bmod{61}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that if $x^9 \equiv 3 \bmod{61}$, then $x^{12}\equiv 34 \bmod{61}$.

The first thing I tried was the obvious:

$$(x^9)^{4/3} \equiv 3^{4/3} \bmod{61}$$
$$x^{12} \equiv 3^{4/3} \bmod{61}$$

But this doesn't get me anywhere.

I've also tried breaking it down by saying that there exists a $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $x^9 - 3 = 61k_1$ and trying to work it towards $x^{12} - 34 = 61k_2$, for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, but again, I didn't get too far.

Comment: I see you too are taking Math 135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $x^{60} = 1$ modulo $61$. This is Fermats Little Theorem (of course $x$ is a not divisible by $61$ so it is applicable).

Thus, $3^7 = (x^9)^7 = x^{63}=x^3$ modulo $61$. 
So you know $x^3$ and the rest is direct.

The general strategy would be to solve $9 k = 12$ modulo $60$, and then compute $x^{12}= (x^{9})^k = 3^k$, but I took a slight shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^9-3$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{61}$ factors as
$$
(x^9-3)=(x^3-4)(x^3-5)(x-45)(x-41)(x-36)
$$
Now every root satisfies $x^{12}\equiv 34 \bmod 61$. This is immediate for $x=45,41,36$ by direct calculation.

Comment: Could you explain the downvote? It seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ It suffices to compute $x^3.$ If  we can solve $\, 9n \equiv 3\pmod{60}$ then we can raise $\,x^9\equiv 3$ to power $n$ obtaining $\,x^3 \equiv 3^n$ But that's easy.